# UITableView didSelect not working in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

When i select any row than didselect is not getting called.It's color also changes to blue on selection. but didSelect is not working.Delegate, DataSources and Table outlet are also connected. Here is my Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    categoryLbl.text = categoryArray[indexPath.row].type
    dataDict.setValue(categoryArray[indexPath.row].type, forKey: "category")
    categoryTable?.isHidden = true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
    categoryTable?.isHidden = true

    self.geCategoryData()

    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(AddFeedbackViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}
```

Comment: have you set a break point and tested once.

Comment: Have you attached your view with your view controller..?

Comment: with out this categoryTable?.isHidden = true try once

Comment: @TusharSharma yes i tried.

Comment: @AnilKumar everthing is working fine except didSelect and tableOutlet is connected.

Comment: @Rahul Gupta so it is not going on that method?

Comment: @TusharSharma yes it is not going.

Comment: @Rahul Gupta can you show more code.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i tried but not working.

Comment: Even i removed this table and again dragged a new table and connected everything but still not working.

Comment: can you show viewDidLoad code.

Comment: Have you any UITapGestureRecognizer set for categoryTable ....?

Comment: @TusharSharma I added code.

Comment: @AnilKumar i ahve not added tapGesture for table.

Comment: add tableView.delegate = self and  tableView.dataSource = self in viewDidLoad and try once.

Comment: @TusharSharma still not working

Comment: Try deleting the didSelect method and retype it. I've had this issue before and then realized I wasn't actually overriding didSelect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, It will solve your problem

```
tap.delegate = self // add this in viewdidLoad()

extension YourViewContoller: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        if touch.view != nil && touch.view!.isDescendantOfView(self.tableView) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: But whats the problem previously it was working but suddenly it got stopped working.

Comment: because when you added the UITapGestureRecognizer() , the tap gesture is eating all your touch events.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

categoryLbl.text = categoryArray[indexPath.row].type
    dataDict.setValue(categoryArray[indexPath.row].type, forKey: "category")
    categoryTable?.isHidden = true

}
```

Comment: Not working.And it will also not work beacuse this code is for swift 2.3 and i am using Swift 3.